# Adding keyStore and trustStore to Gatling requests

Tags: scala, performance-testing, gatling

I've been doing performance testing using Gatling and now need to find a way to add keyStore and trustStore to my requests. Was wondering if that is something I can add in the `HttpProtocolBuilder` or do I have to take a slightly different approach.

Basically is there a Gatling equivalent to the following RestAssured commands?

```
given()
        .keyStore("src/test/resources/fooKeyStore.jks","fooPassword")
        .trustStore("src/test/resources/fooTrustStore.jks","fooPassword")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Was wondering if that is something I can add in the HttpProtocolBuilder

There, you can only use [perUserKeyManagerFactory](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/http/protocol/#peruserkeymanagerfactory) to create a distinct KeyManager for each virtual user. This should be the way to go only if you want to provide different keystores for each virtual user.

You can define the default keystore in [gatling.conf](https://github.com/gatling/gatling/blob/main/gatling-core/src/main/resources/gatling-defaults.conf#L62-L67).

I recommend you let the default trusty TrustManager: you want to run a load test, not secure an application.

Comment: cheers, literally just found out the place on gatling.conf to add them. Can confirm it is easy and works well.